# Please give me an example of a locally nilpotent group such that its derived subgroup is a p-group but its central factor is not torsion.

Tags: group-theory

Please give me an example of a locally nilpotent group 
such that its derived subgroup is a p-group but its central factor is not torsion.

Homework

Comment: "It's central factor"? What central factor? Do you mean $\,G/Z(G)\,$?

Comment: Assuming that central factor means $G/Z(G)$, does a semidirect product of a quasicyclic $p$-group ${\mathbb Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ by an infinite cyclic group with action $x \mapsto x^{1+p}$ work?

Comment: yes Antonio. By central factor I mean G/Z(G)

Comment: Dear Derek, would you please explain more?

Comment: Dear Derek I can't show that your example is locally nilpotent. Would you please help me.